# EF Core add an entity without persisting it in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an EF Core application, which use Entity Framework as ORM. I am in the process of designing a system, which has a feature in which I need to add an entity without persisting it in the database right away. The feature entails the following "use-cases"

1. User adds a new item (System should add the item and related entities without doing `_context.SaveChanges();`)
2. User gets redirected to a new place where he can edit and save the item (actual persistence in the database happens when the item is saved)
3. User discards the item or clicks away from the page (Nothing should be persisted in the database)

I was wondering, if there is a way in which I could achieve the above. More concrete, I'm looking for a way to save unique entities in my context, without doing `_context.SaveChanges();` right away.

I want to do it in a way, so that I easily can persist it in the database, once the user decides to save his edits.

The, in my mind, patchy solution would be to just add the item, however, this will cause problems if the user just clicks away from the edit page. (I might end up having a ton of entities, which doesn't really contain anything)

The obvious choice would be to just add the entity once the save button is clicked - this doesn't however work in this context.

Therefore:

- Is there a way in which I can construct unique database objects in my context that I can edit, without saving to the database right away.

I've read about sequences in EF core, and that may be a way to go?

Comment: I wouldn't use Entity Framework for session storage.  It sounds like you need to build up the data in the user's session somewhere, then when you're ready to commit, persist the whole lot at once.

Comment: Maybe take a step back and look at the bigger picture. Why is this temporary entity making it to you persistence layer at all? Presumably from the tags you are making a web app? Why not keep the "draft" entity in the browser local storage until it's time to persist it?

Comment: EF Core InMemory Database may be?

Comment: @ChrisPickford thats a good point. the user do however also need to add a bunch files which may be alot of data to store client side?

Comment: @JeppeChristensen Storing files to be uploaded? Just store the path then upload when ready to commit via multipart request.

Comment: Why don't use something like Redis for that and when the user is done with his edits , you could persist the data in the database